# How can I change a Block parameter in Simulink with Serial Port?

Tags: matlab, parameters, simulink

I am loading my Simulink Model to a `microprocessor`. After that I want to `change` a value of a `Block parameter`.

In the picture below the data comes to `Matlab Function` block is coming from `Serial Port`. Now, appearently th incoming data is assigned to input `u` of Matlab Function block. In that Matlab Function block I want to write a code that changes , for example, coefficient of `s` in the Transfer Fcn block. Or it can change any other parameter you can give in code hypothetically.

If anybody can give me any solution that would be ver much appreaciated!. Thank you in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Substitute a custom-made subsystem for the transfer function whose parameters have to change, and create the subsystem from basic blocks so that coefficients can be read from signal sources. You might be interested in this

http://blogs.mathworks.com/seth/2011/03/08/how-do-i-change-a-block-parameter-based-on-the-output-of-another-block/

Even if you don't want to change parameters at *every* time step, the restriction

> "[...] calls to `set_param` also preclude the model from ever being compiled
>   into a real-time application."

seems relevant to your case.

Anyway, as far as I know the post linked above still applies in 2014.

Hope that helps.

Comment: +1. Good suggestion. Your parameter becomes a signal as it now changes every time step (potentially) so you can't use the standard transfer function block anymore, but have to reconstruct the transfer function from scratch using (time-dependent) signals rather than (constant) parameters